# Why does change from Spring boot version 2.1.4 to 2.1.5 gives unknown configuration Maven error?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, spring-boot

I had installed Eclipse (actually Spring Tool Suite). It came with Maven. I had created Spring boot starter projects.  Maven was downloading all the dependencies and things were working fine.

Recently, I created a new project.  This time, I noticed an error in pom.xml 
and the problem window (in STS) showing the following:

```
Description Resource    Path                    Location   Type
Unknown     pom.xml     /TestSessionAttribute   line 1     Maven Configuration Problem
```

I noticed that the spring boot version was at 2.1.5 (it was 2.1.4 before).

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

I went ahead and did an update of the project (Maven > Update project) with the 'Force Update of Snapshots/Releases' checked.  This did not resolve the problem. 
I do see the

```
spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar
```

in the m2 repository.

I went back and changed the version to 2.1.4 and then a Maven > Update Project and the errors went away.

Why am I getting the Maven error when version is 2.1.5?

Comment: Have you ran `mvn install`?

Comment: Please try to build on command line first without install only `mvn clean package` ...and see if no error occurs...

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider Since Maven came with STS I did not do anything related to maven.  I am not too familiar with maven.  I am not sure if there is separate installation of maven when one installs Eclipse/STS.

Comment: Maven installed not via Eclipse. If you have STS in Eclipse it's only inside Eclipse. If you need it outside what I recommend downloading it here: https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi  and installation see https://maven.apache.org/install.html

Comment: @khmarbaise I reckoned so. Since it is working as a plugin I am not sure I want to separately install maven again. I am going to see if the maven plug-ins need to be updated.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16846#issuecomment-492792506) link you can fix the issue by downgrading the maven-jar-plugin to 3.1.1 (from 3.1.2). I can confirm that the fix works for my own projects.

Add the following entry to your pom to fix that issue.

```
<properties>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
</properties>
```

An [official bug entry for eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=547340) exists as well.

Comment: Yes, that did it.  Thanks

Comment: Incredible... It worked for me. I spent 1 hour trying to fix it!
Thank you very much

Comment: Worked perfectly! (after Maven->Update Project...)  Thanks.

Comment: Looks like 2.1.6 is also broken with eclipse.. getting a bunch of errors.. :(

Comment: Faced the same issue with 2.2.5 project generated through spring initializr. Adding the above in the pom.xml resolved the issue.

Comment: Updating eclipse (2019-12 or later) fixes the issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know **why** it is broken. I guess it is a broken setting in the eclipse project.

I only know how to solve it:

1. Keep 2.1.5.RELEASE in the pom.xml
2. Close eclipse
3. run `mvn clean eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse`
4. Start eclipse

So all the eclipse related settings will be recreated. It then works as intended. After that you can even "downgrade" the spring version, and it keeps working.

Comment: The latest version of STS comes with Maven plug-ins.  Since there is no separate installation of maven, I am not sure I can run mvn from the command line.  

I did see that when I sent from 2.1.3 to 2.1.4 I had not seen any errors.  But I see the error when I go from 2.1.4 to 2.1.5.  May be some dependency is missing with 2.1.5.  I am still looking into it.

Comment: This does not fix the issue for me. If I do this eclipse complains that the configuration is out of date and once I refresh the maven config from eclipse the error is back.