# Why first line in pom.xml in spring-boot Application showing error... <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Tags: spring-boot

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>Demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>Demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: If you are using Eclipse for development, there is supposed to be an error icon in front of the first line, you can move your cursor to view the error message.

Answer (score 26):

This happening with 2.1.5.RELEASE. Add the following entry to your pom to fix that issue.

```
<properties>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
</properties>
```

[Why does change from Spring boot version 2.1.4 to 2.1.5 gives unknown configuration Maven error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56154266/why-does-change-from-spring-boot-version-2-1-4-to-2-1-5-gives-unknown-configurat)

Answer (score 9):

Just edit properties of file pom.xml
`<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
</properties>`

Comment: It worked. But why it is after adding this line? Maven is not working with java 11?

Answer (score 3):

There is incompatibilities between the version of M2E and the version 3.1.2 of the maven-jar-plugin.

Until the problem is solved by the development teams of M2E or maven-jar-plugins, you have to add in your pom.xml file the following line in order to solve this issue:

```
<build>
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is problem that is mostly occurring in eclipse IDE only. This is scheduled to fix in later version but not sure when.

To resolve this you can add a property to update the maven jar plugin in pom.xml.

```
 <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
</properties>
```

Once you edit the pom.xml, just do an update to your spring boot application.
Right click on Springboot Application>>Maven>>update project.

The error sign from your pom.xml will go away.

Answer (score 0):

Please update  tag in porm.xml

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
     <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
</properties>
```