# when i create web starter project in sts it shows error in pom and java file

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

i install STS . but when i  create web starter project and then select web it shows error on pom file and spring boot cannot be solved error in java file

```
package com.deepak.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyWebAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyWebAppApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.deepak</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyWebApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MyWebApp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Create a new project here and add dependency according to needs https://start.spring.io/

Comment: Ok, so what is the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does change from Spring boot version 2.1.4 to 2.1.5 gives unknown configuration Maven error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56154266/why-does-change-from-spring-boot-version-2-1-4-to-2-1-5-gives-unknown-configurat)

Comment: As advised in the answer to the above add this to the properties block as workaround for an Eclipse bug:`<maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>`