# Unknown `pom.xml` error in every Spring Boot project imported into STS

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, maven, spring-tool-suite

I'm seeing a mysterious error appearing in every newly created project in Spring Tools Suite: the pom.xml file has an `Unknown` error right at the beginning of the file:

[image]

Not sure what this could be attributed to.  I tried disabling Eclipse validations but that doesn't seem to matter, the error persists.  Has anyone seen such a behavior and perhaps knows how to fix it?

I'm using:

Spring Tool Suite 4 
Version: 4.0.0.M7
Build Id: 201712141343

Comment: This answer helped me to resolve the error . https://stackoverflow.com/a/56186480/4214241

Comment: @R.G: Thank you. Indeed, downgrading Maven plugin helps.  Does anyone know what's going on here?  Do newer Eclipse/STS versions have it addressed?

Comment: The answer mentions an eclipse bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=547340#c9

Comment: @SimeonLeyzerzon Yes, you ran into this issue by using outdated software. To avoid this in the future, [enable checking for new releases](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Always_enable_major_upgrades).

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug report regarding the same issue. However, fix has been released. Click `Help > Check for updates` in *Eclipse/STS* and install the newest m2e connector.

If that doesn't work you can downgrade to `<maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>`

```
<properties>
    <java.version>X</java.version>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
</properties>
```

You may also try

Eclipse > Help > Install New Software >
Work with= https://download.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/signed/mavenarchiver/0.17.4/, Enter m2e extensions= Y > Next...

http://download.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/milestones/1.4/