# How to resolve an error in pom.xml file of springboot starter project?

Tags: java

I am getting an error on the first line of the `pom.xml` for every springboot application I create, and an error description is "maven configuration problem".

Here is my error in `pom.xml` file:

[image]

Comment: Please check if this resolves your issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/56186480/4214241

Comment: Have you checked to see if the POM file starts with a Unicode BOM?