# Spring boot project setup error in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, maven

I have created a project a project using https://start.spring.io/, when i import that project into my eclipse it is giving error as

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for 
com.spring:micro-finance:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact 

org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.2.6.RELEASE from/to 
uk.maven.org (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Failed to authenticate with proxy and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM   pom.xml /project-name   line 
5   Maven pom Loading Problem
```

Here is my Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.spring</groupId>
<artifactId>Demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Demo</name>
<description>Demo project in Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

I have added the porxy details in apache-maven-3.6.0\conf\settings.xml

I have an another project which is perfectly running in the eclipse and its spring boot version is 2.1.2.RELEASE, when i change the above project to the version 2.1.2.RELEASE the error is getting resolved.

Comment: Most probably the issue occur because the artifact that you are trying to resolve cannot be found on the proxy server that you are using. Check the maven repo has the particular version of the artifact otherwise use the latest version from the repo.

Comment: Maven repo has that version

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56154266/why-does-change-from-spring-boot-version-2-1-4-to-2-1-5-gives-unknown-configurat Hope it helps!!

Comment: Try building the project outside eclipse through command line like `mvn clean install` so that all the dependencies are resolved and placed in your local maven repo, after that try importing the project again in eclipse.

Comment: @Ananthapadmanabhan and Betty thank for your suggestions, I have made mistake in my setting.xml, after correcting it worked fine.